# Cannot use string in case even though I am using Java 8?

Tags: java, maven

Sorry that I have to ask this quite easy question. I am using OSX with Java 8 installed and maven. But I can't mvn install a code using string in case. Can you point out what's wrong?

mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: zh_TW, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Code error msg

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/Briancheung/Documents/projects/webcompiler/dev/parser/src/main/java/project/Preference.java:[40,23] 
strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
 (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
[INFO] 1 error
```

It seems that maven is not using Java 8 JDK I have installed. Thank you for any response.

java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

javac -version

```
javac 1.8.0_45
```

Comment: Did you check the compilation options to see if `-source 1.5` is there? And what happens if you use option `-source 7`?

Comment: Are you using an IDE or just compiling in console? If you're using an IDE then you need to figure out how to change your source to a higher level, as you're using 1.5. If you're using console, you just need to tag on -source 8

Comment: [Setting the `-source` and `-target` of the Java Compiler](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Comment: As [indicated on the current front page of maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html) the default `source` value is 1.5 and you will have to set it manually to use a newer version.

Comment: @CheungBrian What versions do you get when you run `java -version` and `javac -version`?

Comment: Hi all, I am using OSX terminal to do everything.

Comment: @4castle Is there a way of doing this without touching my pom.xml?

Comment: Why would you not want to put this into you `pom.xml`? The Java version your program is written for seems to me to be a natural part of your project model, something that would belong in the pom.